# Does pg-promise automatically close connections?

Tags: pg-promise

Does pg-promise automatically close connections without needing me to explicitly call client.end() when finished debugging/compiling code?

Comment: [The very first item on the list of features says](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#about): `Automatic connections`. You do not even work with the `client`.

Comment: @vitaly-t thank you for the answer, does this apply to using an express server? meaning do you need to add some cleanup code on SIGTERM to close or will pgp do it automatically there as well, could not find any express examples inside your examples folder